# Get Downloads from github via php api

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to get all downloads from an repo on github with help of https://github.com/ornicar/php-github-api

There is no download Object in this project, so i've created my own:

class Github_Api_Download extends Github_Api{

```
public function getDownloads($repo, $username){
     $string =  'repos/'.urlencode($username).'/'.urlencode($repo).'/downloads';
     $response = $this->get($string);

    die(print_r($response));
    return $response;
}
```

}

When i run this, i'm getting only

*Server Error
HTTP 401: Unauthorized*

1. it should be possible to get this without authentication too, because if i use the url in the browser, it's working
2. my authentication is working, because all the actions (e.g. create new repo,etc..) are working fine

Anybody can help me?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for this earlier, so I wrote my own little function and posted it on my blog. Hope this helps.

[Check this out](http://hypnorabbit.com/github-api-v3-php-quick-download/)